# Wording of comparing X vs Y and X vs Z but not X vs Y vs Z

Tags: technical-writing, academic-writing, titles

As per the title I compared my system against two other systems separately but I'm worried about it coming across as that it was a three way comparison.

Neither of the below titles convey what I want to, what is the best way to word a comparison such as this or would it be better being split into two chapters?

```
Comparison of egocentric camera vs. static camera vs. dense sensor placement.

Comparison of egocentric camera against static camera and dense sensor placement.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clarifier you want is "respectively." It's fine in running copy, or even as a caption, but clunks as a header.

> Comparison of egocentric camera against static camera and dense sensor placement, respectively

For a headline, you might try emphasizing the idea that there are two comparisons with some redundancy:

> Comparisons of Egocentric Camera vs. Static Camera and vs. Dense Sensor Placement

Answer (score 0):

"Here, we see that the egocentric camera is being compared with either the static camera or the dense sensor placement." You can also add "Please note that this is not a comparison between the static camera and dense sensor placement. Such a comparison is inappropriate because ..."

Comment: As simply a title, I would write: "Egocentric Camera and How It Compares to either Static Camera or Dense Sensor Placement"